# How I can cut html table into separate tables?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a html doc parsed by JSoup. In this table there are several rows:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Some of the rows are kind of headers - I find those rows with Jsoup `select(...)` method. So I have `Elements` object containing all rows that are headers. Lets say it looks like this:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr1">...</tr> 
        <tr id="tr2">...</tr> // this is header
        <tr id="tr3">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr4">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr5">...</tr> // this is header
        <tr id="tr6">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Id attributes are just for this example - int real case there are not id attributes in parsed html.

What I need is to get 2 tables (2 `Element` objects containing each table), one for each header, containing all rows below given header but above next header. So I expect:

```html
<table> // Element 1
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr3">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr4">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table> // Element 2
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr6">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can any1 help me with this task?

Comment: ??? What do you mean? I don't have influence on the layout of parsed doc and I have to transform it...

Comment: `jsoup` *parses* HTML.  It wouldn't manipulate the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good exercise to test JSoup's capacity of dom handling. Below is the snippet you need. The code is pretty much self-explanatory (`createElement` creates an element and so on), but if you need any clarification let me know:

```
Elements tables = new Elements();
for (Element headerTR : headerRows) {
    Element tbody = doc.createElement("tbody");
    Element firstSiblingTR = headerTR.nextElementSibling();
    if (firstSiblingTR != null) {
        Element secondSiblingTR = firstSiblingTR.nextElementSibling();
        tbody.appendChild(firstSiblingTR);
        if (secondSiblingTR != null) {
            tbody.appendChild(secondSiblingTR);
        }
    }
    Element table = doc.createElement("table");
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    tables.add(table);
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body>"+
    "<table>" +
    "  <tbody>" +
    "    <tr><td>1</td></tr>" +
    "    <tr class='header'><td>2</td></tr>" + // class added to simulate ur list
    "    <tr><td>3</td></tr>" +
    "    <tr><td>4</td></tr>" +
    "    <tr class='header'><td>5</td></tr>" + // class added to simulate ur list
    "    <tr><td>6</td></tr>" +
    "  </tbody>" +
    "</table>" +
    "</body></html>");

    Elements headerRows = doc.getElementsByClass("header"); // simulating ur list

    Elements tables = new Elements();
    for (Element headerTR : headerRows) {
        Element tbody = doc.createElement("tbody");
        Element firstSiblingTR = headerTR.nextElementSibling();
        if (firstSiblingTR != null) {
            Element secondSiblingTR = firstSiblingTR.nextElementSibling();
            tbody.appendChild(firstSiblingTR);
            if (secondSiblingTR != null) {
                tbody.appendChild(secondSiblingTR);
            }
        }
        Element table = doc.createElement("table");
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        tables.add(table);
    }
    System.out.println(tables); // print <table> list
}
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good but you check just two siblings after each header. I don't know how many rows are between two consecutive header rows. So I have to check siblings of each header row in a loop to determine if given sibling is not next header row....

Comment: I found method I needed - `Element.elementSiblingIndex()` it returns index in siblings table. So now it will be easy comparing index of each row.